# Error while installing tensorflow on window 10s with python 3.9.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip, tensorflow2.0

So I've installed python 3.9.1 and I tried to install tensorflow using `pip3 install tensorflow` and `pip install tensorflow` directly in command prompt, and then I created virtual environment for python using `python3 -m venv venv` in a project dir, and when I started it and tried to install tensorflow using pip it again failed.

Error messsage was this:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

Python version: `Python 3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]`

Comment: The latest version available on pypi is for 3.8. https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#files

Comment: @Axe319 So I should downgrade python to 3.8, right?

Comment: Unless you are willing to attempt to build from source as described here. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44485#issuecomment-751459057

Comment: According to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44485#issuecomment-786086270, we have `py39` wheels in recent `tf-nightly` and `tf-nightly-cpu` projects only on linux and windows for now (i.e on 26th Feb 2021). Please test `nightly` before the `2.5` release. Thanks